# Removing Ttk Notebook Tab Dashed Line

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm trying to make a tkinter app that doesn't look like a tkinter app. I'm using a ttk Notebook, and the tabs have this little dotted line around the text when they're selected. It looks terrible, and I can't find a way to remove it using either styles or config. Here's a screenshot to clarify:

[image]

Edit for code (I don't think it'll be terribly helpful, since I'm actually just trying to remove a default style thing.):

Here is the notebook creation:

```
tabs = ttk.Notebook(mainframe, width=319, height=210, style=style.Notebook)
tabs.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=('n', 'w', 'e', 's'))
tabs.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
tabs.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Filling it in:

```
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
tab1_frame = ttk.Frame(tab1, style=style.Frame)
tab1_frame.pack(anchor='center', expand=1, fill='both')
# stick some widgets in
progress = ttk.Progressbar(tab1_frame, orient="horizontal", length=300, mode="determinate")
progress.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=2, padx=style.padding, pady=style.padding)
progress['maximum'] = 1000
progress['value'] = 500
# More widgets
# Another tab
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabs)
tab2_frame = ttk.Frame(tab2, style=style.Frame)
tab2_frame.pack(anchor='center', expand=1, fill='both')
# blah blah
```

Relevant styles:

```
style_config = Style()
style_config.theme_use('default')

style_config.configure(self.Notebook,
    background=self.dark,
    borderwidth=0)

style_config.configure(self.Tab,
   background=self.dark,
   foreground='white',
   padding=self.padding,
   borderwidth=0)
style_config.map(self.Tab,
    background=[('selected', self.color1)])
```

Comment: some code would help me help you

Comment: I don't know if it would, since this is default to all the themes (I'm using default), and I'm trying to remove it. I'll update my answer though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can remove this focus mark by altering the sub elements of tab widget. Ttk widgets are decomposed in [subelements](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/styles.html). The layout of these elements is described through `layout` method (or in a layout parameter of `theme_create`). Here is a command to remove layout marks (you can apply it directly to Tab, or any other derived theme), the commented part is what lead previously to drawing the focus (retrieved through `style.layout("Tab")`)

```
style.layout("Tab",
[('Notebook.tab', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
    [('Notebook.padding', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
        #[('Notebook.focus', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
            [('Notebook.label', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''})],
        #})],
    })],
})]
)
```

A more hacky way could be to alter the color of this focus mark, for instance to draw it the same color as background

```
style.configure("Tab", focuscolor=style.configure(".")["background"])
```

Comment: Awesome; I will try this out today and see how it works!

Answer (score 2):

On a Windows machine, if I create a theme and use "classic" as parent, the ugly dashed border is also not drawn.

```
style.theme_create( "Florina", parent="classic", settings={
    "TLabel": {"configure": {"background": BACKGROUND }},
    "TFrame": {"configure": {"background": BACKGROUND }},
    "TNotebook": {
        "configure": {"background": BACKGROUND, "tabmargins": [1, 5, 2, 0] }},
    "TNotebook.Tab": {
        "configure": {"background": DARKBG, "padding": [5, 2] },
        "map":       {"background": [("selected", BACKGROUND)],
                      "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])]
                      } } } )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the focus color using `theme_create()`:

```
wthm = ttk.Style()
    
wthm.theme_create('wtheme', parent='default', settings={
       'TNotebook.Tab': {
           'configure': {'focuscolor':{
                             'configure':{
                                 '.':'<your_color>'}
                         }}
})

wthm.theme_use('wtheme')
```