# Tkinter Treeview, only the first value in a list being displayed

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my code for inserting:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class SummaryTree(ttk.Treeview):
    def __init__(self, parent, kwargs):
        ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, parent, columns=2, selectmode=tk.NONE, show='tree', takefocus=False)

        self.column('#1', anchor=tk.W)
        self.tag_configure('evenrow', background='#cecece')

        for index, item in enumerate(kwargs.items()):
            if index % 2 == 0:
                self.insert('', tk.END, text=item[0], values=item[1], tags=('evenrow',))
            else:
                self.insert('', tk.END, text=item[0], values=item[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    kwargs = {
        'Soda': [
            'Sprite',
            'Mountain Dew',
            'Coke'
        ],
        'Numbers': [
            5,
            6,
            7
        ]
    }
    SummaryTree(root, kwargs).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

For some reason this code is only inserting the first value in the lists. I'm not quite sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Your example is not complete.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have created the minimal verifiable example of my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [`ttk.Treeview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview) documentation, the **columns** option is:

> A list of column identifiers, specifying the number of columns
>   and their names

So if you want your Treeview to have 3 columns named `1`, `2`, and `3`, you should write:

```
ttk.Treeview.__init__(self, parent, columns=[1, 2, 3], ...)
```

Comment: Ahh now I understand. I am just blind. Thanks for the help. Do you know how to keep the **text** item in a treeview from being focused so that it doesn't have the dashed lines around it?

Comment: You're welcome :) To remove the dashed lines on focus, try to edit the ttk style as shown here: [Removing Ttk Notebook Tab Dashed Line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23399786/4084269)

Comment: I understand the code but unfortunately I don't know the layout string to use. I have tried Treeview.Cell, Treeview.Column, Treeview.Text, and all of them report errors because they don't exist

Comment: I'm also not sure which one you should use. Maybe you can ask it as a new question...