# How to change the focus styling of a tkinter ttk.Treeview cell

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

Even though my Treeview has the option `takefocue=False`, the text in the cells is still taking focus somehow. Specifically the text column when I do `tree.insert('', tk.END, text='Some Text', values=5)` is taking focus, meaning there is a dashed line around `Some Text`. I was able to find this [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354303/removing-ttk-notebook-tab-dashed-line/23399786#23399786), but I am not sure of the layout string I need to change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Tcl/Tk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/26993) wiki, the following 5 styles can be used to customize a `ttk.Treeview()` widget:

```
"Treeview"
"Treeview.Heading"
"Treeview.Row"
"Treeview.Cell"
"Treeview.Item"
```

Using [`.layout()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style.layout), you can retrieve the layout specifications of each style:

```
style = ttk.Style()
style.layout("Treeview.Item")
```

It turns out that the `"Treeview.Item"` style has a `"Treeitem.focus"` layout mark. If you [comment it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23399786/4084269) when overwriting the layout, the focus drawing behavior (and the dashed line) will disappear:

```
style = ttk.Style()

style.layout("Treeview.Item",
[('Treeitem.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': 
    [('Treeitem.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
    ('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
    #('Treeitem.focus', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': '', 'children': [
         ('Treeitem.text', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
    #]})
    ],
})]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this was just what I was looking for. Thanks so much!