# Remove dotted line around notebook tab tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have recently being trying to make pokedex using tkinter python and I was going well with it but a problem occurred, which made the whole interface ugly!

There is a dotted border which is coming in every active button and notebook tab which is spoiling look of the whole program.

Also the code of styling didn't worked out !

NOTE: I tried using focuscolor but it didn't help...

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('700x500')

Style().configure('lefttab.TNotebook', tabposition='wn')
Style().configure('TNotebook.Tab', font='Courier 16')

notebook = Notebook(root, style='lefttab.TNotebook')
f1 = tk.Frame(notebook, width=500, height=400)
f2 = tk.Frame(notebook, width=500, height=400)

notebook.add(f1, text='Kantodex Vx')
notebook.add(f2, text='  Attacks  ')

notebook.pack(anchor=tk.NW)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A picture of the "dotted border" would certainly help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing Ttk Notebook Tab Dashed Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354303/removing-ttk-notebook-tab-dashed-line)

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-remove-ttk-notebook-tab-dashed-line-tkinter