# how to remove dotted line on tabMenu in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, tabpanel, tabmenu

[image]

as you see image, each tabMenu has dotted line after tabMenu click
how to remove this dotted line?
bottom is source code thank you.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk

    tabposition = ttk.Style()
    tabposition.configure('TNotebook', sticky='w', tabposition='sw')
    
    style = ttk.Style()
    
    tabposition.configure("Tab", focuscolor=style.configure(".")["background"])
    
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(root, width=1450, height=910)
    notebook.pack(fill="y",expand=False)
    notebook.place(x=526)

    def newtab2():
        frame0 = Frame(root)
        notebook.add(frame0, text="First Input")

    addSheet = Button(root, text="Enter", command=newtab2, borderwidth=1)
    addSheet.place(x=10, y=159, width=41, height=41)
```

Comment: Does this answer the questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354303/removing-ttk-notebook-tab-dashed-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to say:

1. When you want to add a frame to a `ttk.Notebook`, use that as the **master** for the frame. In your code, it was given `root`
2. No need to use new `ttk.Style()`. Instead, set the layout of the original `ttk.Style()`

Given below is the corrected code. Note that the height of the `ttk.Notebook` is changed by me. You can change it later on.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root=Tk()
tabposition = ttk.Style()
tabposition.configure('TNotebook', sticky='w', tabposition='sw')
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root, width=1450, height=510)
notebook.pack(fill="both",expand=1)
tabposition.layout("Tab",
[('Notebook.tab', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
    [('Notebook.padding', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
        #[('Notebook.focus', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'nswe', 'children':
            [('Notebook.label', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': ''})],
        #})],
    })],
})]
)
def newtab2():
    frame0 = Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(frame0, text="First Input")
addSheet = Button(root, text="Enter", command=newtab2, borderwidth=1)
addSheet.place(x=10, y=159, width=41, height=41)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it solves your question @graphicdesigner00000