# Is there a way to remove the selection indicator in a ttk Notebook tab

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm using a ttk Notebook in my Python app with the "winnative" theme. With some adaptions made, this looks quite nice to me, but there's this ugly rectangle around the text in the selected tab (see image), which I would like to get rid of.
Is there any styling option that removes this or makes it invisible?
[image]

Thanks,
Gerhard

Comment: You might try looking to see if it's part of the style layout for the TNotebook.Tab class.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my question is a duplicate of this post:
[Removing Ttk Notebook Tab Dashed Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354303/removing-ttk-notebook-tab-dashed-line)

The solution posted there works fine.