# Delete little lines when ttk.notebook header is selected

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like delete the little lines around the headers of ttk.notebook when a header is selected.

```
            ".": {
                "configure": {
                    "background": '#F0F8FF',  # All colors except for active tab-button
                    "font": 'white'
                }
            },
            "TNotebook": {
                "configure": {
                    "background": '#F0F8FF',  # color behind the notebook
                    "tabmargins": [0, 0, 0, 0],
                    # [left margin, upper margin, right margin, margin beetwen tab and frames]
                }
            },
            "TNotebook.Tab": {
                "configure": {
                    "background": 'blue',  # Color of non selected tab-button
                    "padding": [5, 2],
                    # [space beetwen text and horizontal tab-button border, space between text and vertical tab_button border]
                    "font": ('JetBrains Mono', 11, 'bold')
                },
                "map": {
                    "background": [("selected", '#d0e8ff')],  # Color of active tab
                    "expand": [("selected", [1, 1, 1, 0])]  # [expanse of text]
                }
            }
```

It's probably here that we can modify that parameter.

[image]

Comment: You can start by having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354303/removing-ttk-notebook-tab-dashed-line

Comment: thanks, I didn't know what search